# Passing intents

Tags: java, android

I'm a newb at Java, but know python.

I put an EditText in my xml, with a *number* input type. When someone inputs a number, I want it to get multiplied by, say, 80

this is my main activity code

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

then the displaymessage activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
int ma = Integer.parseInt(message.trim());
int result = ma * 80;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(result);


    setContentView(textView);
}
```

When input a number and send the messagem the app crashes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Why do you need an Intent to do this?

Comment: well comrade im a newb so if you please tell me how else i could ... :3

Comment: oic...you want to display the result in another activity

Comment: According to the code I'm not clear what you try to do here. ... ?

Comment: yes, just for now, as a test, or say an idea of how to do it later

Comment: zussee im trying to mutliply an integer by and interger and have it display on another activity

Comment: @BenKogos Please post the exact error message as well as your complete code. You have left out the class names which makes the code you have given incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

I assume this is a member variable. Calling `getIntent()` at this point in your code is an error. You should move this and the rest of your member variables to `onCreate()`.

**Further reading:**

[Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

[The Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Comment: ok memeber variable. pls explain to said newb. I thought to put it oustide onCreate() so it can always be present, not only when the activity is started

Comment: @BenKogos Why do you need it to always be present? Are there other methods that need to use this variable?

Comment: @BenKogos I also suggest that you read a good Java tutorial that explains the basics of classes.